# Specify reason for flagging off topic

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging

When flagging a question as Off Topic I have to hope the the moderator reviewing the flag spots the same problem I do. I'd like to be able to specify a reason for a question being off topic. This way we can point to specific areas of the FAQ to clarify my reasoning for flagging off topic.

Is there merit to this request?

Comment: Leave a comment that says what you think, then when I check out the question, I'll spot your comment and I may or may not agree with you

Comment: Is that the official process or just how you like to do it?

Comment: Well there's no way to both flag for off-topic and send me a message. So leave a message for everyone to see (so I don't necessarily have to) and just use the boiler plate flag.

Comment: or flag -> it needs ♦ moderator attention -> other -> enter your comment

Comment: But if you post the comment on the question, then hopefully people will learn why their post is off-topic and if a moderator then comes by to close it, they don't have to post some boilerplate explanation

Answer (score 3):

> This way we can point to specific areas of the FAQ to clarify my reasoning for flagging off topic.

If your intent to make clear about reason why you're flagging/voting to close and ensure that the OP sees *why* you're voting to close, then it's best to leave a comment.  Your flag message contents are confidential and visible *only* to Mods. Once you've left a comment, go by the usual, Flag -> It doesn't Belong here -> Off-topic route.

Otherwise, as mentioned the other route is flag -> it needs ♦ moderator attention -> other -> enter your comment - but in this case, you're telling this *only* to the Mod who's acting on this ( and other Mods who might investigate the question) instead of guiding the OP as to why he shouldn't be asking such a question